# iptables + nat to internal web server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

We run ubuntu on our gateway machine. We have a DNAT iptables rule sending traffic on 80 and 3306 to an internal ip address that runs a webserver. It doesn't work at all.

eth1 is the wan interface, eth0 is the local one

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -s 192.168.2.173 -j ACCEPT --dports 25,80,443,465,3306
-A OUTPUT -d 173.201.37.214 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $EXT_IP -i eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.173:80
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d  $EXT_IP -i eth1 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.173:3306
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.173 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That "firewall" is a complete mess. I would probably blow it away and start over.

Comment: Just to expand on @MichaelHampton - you are filtering in your NAT table (instead of the FILTER table), there are chains doing nothing, and no commenting (hint: `-m comment`). As to your original question, the counters on the rules in the PREROUTING chain are 0 - this suggests that the traffic you are expecting to DNAT hasn't even hit the box (or you haven't tested it since you last reset the counters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need the corresponding rules in the filter table to allow the traffic through the filter. The rules you've posted only handle the NAT part.</strike>

```
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.5 -i eth1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.5 -i eth1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

EDIT: OP didn't include full output in first post.

Comment: I edited my answer to include all of the lines from the iptables relevant to our web server

Comment: That suggests you have yet more lines, and they can interfere with each other.  Could you post instead the entire outputs of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`?  Also, the `INPUT` line currently shown in the question looks to me like it should have `-d 192.168.2.173`, not `-s 192.168.2.173`.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Answer (score -1):

You need POSTROUTING rules as well, for instance

```
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth1 -m multiport --sports 80,3306 -s 192.168.2.173 -j SNAT --to-source $EXT_IP
```

Comment: Added that but to no avail. Testing http externally still gets me connection refused.